# Adjust EditText with Seekbar

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-seekbar

I have a SeekBar and EditText.I would like to create a % slider that when the user slides the Seekbar, it adjusts the EditText field.

i tried this:

```
    mInterestRateEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
    if (i >= 0 && i <= 100) {
      mInterestRateSeekBar.setProgress(50); 
    }
  }
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
});

mInterestRateSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    mInterestRateEditText.setText(progress + "");
  }

  @Override
  public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

  }
});
```

but all it does is the second i try sliding the slider, it locks the EditText to 0, and I cannot move the slider?

Comment: you are creating a loop. As soon as you slide, you set a new text. So the text gets changed and afterTextChanged gets called. Then the progress of the seekbar is changed again, which changes the text, which changes the seekbar, which.... you know.

Comment: lol thanks!!! fixed it after you said this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already stated in my comment, you are creating a loop. Changing the Seekbar, changes the text. This changes the seekbar again.

Simple solution: work with a boolean.

```
     boolean changedProgrammatically;

     mInterestRateEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
    if(!changedProgrammatically){
        if (i >= 0 && i <= 100) {
          mInterestRateSeekBar.setProgress(50); 
        }

    }else{
changedProgrammatically = false;
}
      }
      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
    });

    mInterestRateSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    changedProgrammatically = true;
        mInterestRateEditText.setText(progress + "");
      }

      @Override
      public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

      }
    });
```